# Output from “mkpasswd -c” differs with “cat /etc/passwd | grep $USER”

Tags: cygwin

I have noticed that my `$HOME` becomes different from `~` after running some SSH commands. I would like to understand what is causing this difference.

I am using Cygwin's SSH:

```
$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh
```

This is what I see:

```
$ echo $HOME
/c/Users/axxx

$ echo ~
/home/axxx
```

While investigating this I noticed that `/etc/passwd | grep $USER` differs from `mkpasswd -c`. I expected them to be the same, and when `$HOME` and `~` become distinct, `~` equals the home directory corresponding to the output of `mkpasswd -c` while `$HOME` equals the entry for the home directory in `/etc/passwd`.

In addition to the location of the home directory, the entries for User ID and Group ID are also distinct. There is a difference in the username also, in `/etc/passwd`, I noticed my username is of the form `dxxx+axxx` where `dxxx` is my machine name, while in the output of `mkpasswd -c`, my username is simply `axxx`.

[Added Later]

I noticed ~ is picked up from db_home from /etc/nsswitch.conf and $HOME corresponds to the entry in /etc/passwd.

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/profile`. It explains exactly how `HOME` is set.

Comment: Thanks I noticed it uses /usr/bin/install. Any idea where mkpasswd -c it getting its data from?

Comment: No idea. You could look at the source code ...

Comment: Most from the windows info for the current user.